# -c argument when generating Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, devise

I am following a tutorial for setting up authentication in a Rails application with devise and devise_jwt, and I can not find any documentation anywhere for what the **-c** argument does in this command:

```
rails g devise:controllers users -c sessions registrations
```

Could anyone provide some information about what it does?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the source code of the [controller generator](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/generators/devise/controllers_generator.rb) of the `devise` gem:

> ```
>    Create inherited Devise controllers in your app/controllers folder.
>
>    Use -c to specify which controller you want to overwrite.
>    If you do no specify a controller, all controllers will be created.
>    For example:
>
>      rails generate devise:controllers users -c=sessions
>
>    This will create a controller class at app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb like this:
>
>      class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
>        content...
>      end
> ```